# Finding the middle number in an array; I understand how to do it but can't make it work. :/ (Coral)

Tags: arrays, logic

Although my code works, it's not the way the question wants it to be solved and I'd like to know the correct way.

The question is:

> Given a sorted list of integers, output the middle integer. Assume the
> number of integers is always odd.
>
> Ex: If the input is 2 3 4 8 11 -1 (a negative indicates end), the
> output is:
>
> 4 The maximum number of inputs for any test case should not exceed 9
> positive values. If exceeded, output "Too many inputs".
>
> Hint: Use an array of size 9. First, read the data into an array. Then,
> based on the number of items, find the middle item.

My code:

```
integer userInput
integer i
integer mid
integer array(20) number

userInput = 1

for i = 0; userInput >= 0; i = i + 1
   if number[i] > -1
      userInput = Get next input
      number[i] = userInput

i = i - 1
mid = i / 2

if i > 9
   Put "Too many inputs" to output
elseif i % 2 == 0
   Put number[mid - 1] to output
else
   Put number[mid] to output
```

The problem states that the array has to be configured to a size of 9 but with 9 or 10, the program fails and I don't know why so I set it to 20 out of frustration. I've tried this problem multiple other ways like using a while loop

```
while number[i] > -1
```

but for some reason that causes it to never end even though each set of inputs does have a `-1` in it. There are other ways I've forgotten but which resulted in an output of `-1000000000` instead of any of the actual numbers. I'm at a loss but at least I got it working to some degree.

I asked my teacher for help and all he said was: "Your difficulty relates to your "logic" in setting up and using the array. Try starting over, from scratch"

I've started from scratch about a dozen times and I'm not seeing what he's saying. Is there some way to set up an array in Coral that I'm unaware of?

Comment: your code works just fine, you said that the loop would never end that is because you would have forgotten to give -1 at the end and to be clear your code works fine with 10 array elements also just make sure to give the right input: my input was 55 79 89 87 45 47 44 75 36 -1 and the output was 45 which is correct I don't understand why are you getting a wrong output or error while executing. check this link: https://corallanguage.org/simulator/

Answer (score 0):

The program fails because they mandate you need to set the array to 9.
However, they sneakily input the negative number that should stop the program as the 10th input, which would act outside the array range of 9.

So the best thing to do is to set the array to the next highest odd integer: 11

Just change this line:
`integer array(20) number` to `integer array(11) number`

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else runs across this, I myself was also at the mercy of being too complex with this particular one.
Here is the Coral program for this one that passed all 10 tests

Submission passed all tests
Total score: 10 / 10

```
integer userInts
integer i
integer mid
integer array(9) n

userInts = Get next input

while (userInts >=0) and (i < n.size)
   n[i] = userInts
   userInts = Get next input     
   i = i + 1
     
if userInts >=0
   Put "Too many inputs" to output
else
   mid = i / 2
   Put n[mid] to output
```

Answer (score 0):

This is easier done in other languages. But this solution should work.

```
integer int
integer array(12) userNum
integer array(?) myArray
integer i
integer middleNum
integer counter
integer x
integer userInput

for i = 0; i < userNum.size; i = i + 1
   userNum[i] = -1

userNum[0] = Get next input

for i = 0;userNum[i] >= 0; i = i + 1
   userInput = Get next input
   userNum[i + 1] = userInput
   counter = counter + 1

if counter > 9
   Put "Too many inputs" to output
else
   myArray.size = counter
   for i = 0; i < myArray.size; i = i + 1
      myArray[i] = userNum[i]
   
int = myArray.size % 2

if int == 1
   middleNum = myArray.size / 2
   Put myArray[middleNum] to output
```

Comment: It would be useful to explain your approach.  The asker was specifically confused about how to set things up.  I realized they proposed starting over from scratch, but it's helpful to provide more supporting text with your answer by explaining the part that you think may be different from what the asker tried in their approach.

Answer (score -1):

```
integer array(9) numList
integer userNum
integer i
integer midNum
integer counter
integer ovrLmt
counter = 0
ovrLmt = 0
i = 0

userNum = Get next input
while userNum > 0 
if i <= 8
  numList[i] = userNum
  userNum = Get next input
  i = i + 1
else
  ovrLmt = 1
  userNum = Get next input
if ovrLmt == 0
  midNum = i / 2
  Put numList[midNum] to output
else
Put "Too many inputs" to output
```